# transform nested object into another tree

Tags: javascript, object, tree, transformation

I've been trying to transform nested object to another tree object but without success. I can't figure out its solution, so any help would be appreciated.

**Expected output**

```
[
    {
        "duration": 2117538,
        "duration_min": 1001,
        "duration_max": 201530,
        "input": 0,
        "output": 0,
        "label": "down",
        "id": "0",
        "children": [
            {
                "duration": 211538,
                "duration_min": 1001,
                "duration_max": 201530,
                "input": 0,
                "output": 0,
                "boxes": 0,
                "label": "other",
                "id": "0-1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "duration": 1538,
                        "duration_min": 1001,
                        "duration_max": 201530,
                        "input": 0,
                        "output": 0,
                        "boxes": 0,
                        "id": "0-1-0",
                        "label": "no resource",
                    },
                  
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, object's descendants are put into children and consequent id field was added.
And in the example below, we have an object which consists of `values` key and its children, which is `other`. Deep down, there is `no resource` key that only has `values` key which means there will be no children array.

Let's see input format and its structure. In `data` object, there is key `down` and its value, which is an object. Inside that object there are `values` and `other`. Keys that is not `values`, are put into children.

**Given input**

```
const data = {
  "down": {
      "values": {
          "duration": 2117538,
          "duration_min": 1001,
          "duration_max": 201530,
          "input": 0,
          "output": 0,
          "boxes": 0,
      },
      "other": {
          "no resource": {
              "values": {
                  "duration": 1538,
                  "duration_min": 1001,
                  "duration_max": 201530,
                  "input": 0,
                  "output": 0,
                  "boxes": 0,
              }
          },
          "values": {
              "duration": 211538,
              "duration_min": 1001,
              "duration_max": 201530,
              "input": 0,
              "output": 0,
              "boxes": 0,
          }
      }
  }
}
```

**What I tried**

```
function getTransformData(object, name = 'total') {
    return Object.entries(object).map(function ([key, value]) {
      
      if (key === 'values') {
        return { ...value, label: name };
      }
      
      if (value.values) {
        return { ...value.values, label: key, children: getTransformData(value, key) };
      }

    });
}


console.log(getTransformData(data))
```

But this doesn't work as needed.

Comment: How would the input look if the output would have children arrays with more than just one object?

Comment: @trincot [input example](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xxm3khhn) added example there to your request, tell me if link is not working, I will add to question

Comment: I can see it, but is not clear to make how things relate to eachother in the input format. I think a bit more in-depth explanation of the input format is needed in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been solved.

```
function transformNestedObject({values,...children}, id, duration) {
  duration = duration || values.duration;
  children = Object.entries(children).map(([key, value],i)=>{
      const _id = id ? id +"-" + i : ''+i;
      const durationPercent = (value.values.duration / duration * 100.0).toFixed(2) + '%';
      return {
        id: _id,
        label: key,
        durationPercent,
        ...transformNestedObject( value, _id, duration)
      }
    });
    
    if (id) {
      return {...values, children};
    }
    
    return children;
}

console.log(transformNestedObject(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
function to_tree(d, c = []){
   var r = {false:[], true:[]}
   var vals = []
   var k = 0;
   for (var i of Object.keys(d)){
     r[i === 'values'].push(d[i])
   }
   for (var i of r[true]){
     vals.push({...i, 'id':[...c, k].map(x => x.toString()).join('-')});
     k++;
   }
   for (var i of r[false]){
      if (vals.length){
         vals[vals.length-1]['children'] = to_tree(i, [...c, k])
      }
      else{
         vals = [...vals, ...to_tree(i, c)]
      }
   }
   return vals
}
```